# Cannot create a data frame from character matrix from a .pdf with the correct columns in R due to multiple rows in certain cells in the source table

Tags: r, pdf, character, multirow

Saved this link https://www.otcmarkets.com/otcapi/company/financial-report/317949/content as a pdf to my computer as a pdf and used pdf_text to read it into R.
Trying to create a data frame out of the 5th entry. I split it at the line breaks \n.  The problem is that the cells on the source table have varying numbers of lines.

```
report <- "C:/Users/projects/report.pdf" #the .pdf of the link above
txt <- pdf_text(report)
x<-str_split(txt[5],"\n")
s<-x[[1]]
excess_end <- str_which(s,"OTC Markets Group Inc")
out <- c(excess_end:length(s))
s<-s[-out]
s
```

The problem is that because the table has some cells with multiple entries, the line breaks don't match up to what should be each line of the proposed data frame.  I would typically use a string_split_fixed at the spaces (s<-str_split_fixed(s,"\s\s+",n=10) but the columns become mis-aligned due to the rows that spill-out from the multi-row cells, e.g. [1] below (this is before trying the str_split_fixed).   The first row below for example is overflow from the original source cell on the table.

> head(s)
> [1] "                                                 Common                          Silverback Capital          Debt"
> [2] "    03/01/19      New Issue        523,500                    0.0285       NO                                             Unrestricted    R.144"
> [3] "                                                  Shares                           *Alison Biddle          Conversion"
> [4] "                                                                                  Jefferson Street"
> [5] "                                                 Common                                                      Debt"
> [6] "    03/19/19      New Issue        584,795                    0.0342       NO        Capital LLC                          Unrestricted    R.144"

Is there another way to import this data that will give me a character string I can work with?

I tried str_split_fixed at the spaces and I tried a variety of other splits, but I cannot get the columns aligned properly.

Comment: Is this a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896986/scraping-pdf-tables-with-empty-cells

Comment: Or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683947/r-python-converting-pdfs-to-tables/74696177#74696177

Comment: This does not appear to be a duplicate of either of those issues.  Thank you.